# How does PCS on 4l60e work?

Tags: automatic-transmission, electronics, 4l60e

Looking at the pinout for the connector for the 4l60e there are 2 pins for the pressure control solenoid. 1 pin for HIGH, and 1 pin for LOW.

Does this mean the PCS can only ever be in 1 of 2 positions? I was under the impression that the PCS would be post width modulated to get more varying fluid pressure or is this just not the case.

If the PCS can only ever be in 1 of 2 positions is it as simple as applying 12v to the HIGH pin if you want high pressure and  likewise for Low pressure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pulse Width Modulation (PWM) can easily be achieved with two wires. All PWM does is hold one wire constant and rapidly pulse the other between 1k and 10k times a second. By changing the relation ship of how long the pulse is on versus how long the pulse is off the duty cycle is changed.

Both the wires from the pressure control solenoid go to the PCM. The probable operation of the solenoid is that there is a default position of the solenoid in the middle where the transmission is derivable. This position is held with springs so that if control is lost the solenoid will default there. This is there to provide a limp mode in case of electrical failure.

From here to raise the pressure one line is held at a constant polarity and the other is PWMed. This will cause the solenoid to move from the default position in the direction of raising the pressure. To lower the pressure the same thing happens but now with reversed polarity. This will cause the solenoid to move from the default position in the direction of lowering the pressure.